# Vue App won't host on firebase properly its either the script in index.HTML or main.js but i can't get it to work?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, firebase-hosting

So I have a Vue app which I had tested with npm run dev and npm run build everything was going fine and working perfectly but then when I try to host on firebase and move all of the related folders into the public folder it doesn't seem to be able to read either the script tag in the index Html or the main.js folder that creates the Vue app so I just end up with a blank white screen with only a title and an icon in the tab no rest of the app or anything in router-view.

Heres the index.Html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/icon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> Web page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Heres the main.js which may also be the problem.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './style/index.css'
import router from '../src/router/index'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'




createApp(App).use(router).use(createPinia()).mount('#app')
```

As I said it all worked okay through the builds and when I previewed it before hand but when I try to firebase serve in the terminal it only gets the title and the icon.png from the index.html page so it's either not reading it there or on the main.js because the app and router-view just don't show up anymore.

If anyone knows how to find out which one isn't working exactly or how to fix this so that it works I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: have you done step 1 in debugging? i.e. check the browser console for errors? are you using `vite` ... my `main.js` imports using `@/App.vue` and `@/router/index` etc because `src` doesn't exist in a bundled App

Comment: You shouldn't be uploading the raw code. You should be executing "npm run build" and then uploading what is compiled in the "dist" folder.